# Django test runner with multi threaded live test server and custom sql_flush function error

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I am trying to use this snippet to implement threaded live test server for my django test runner. We have custom sql_flush function which we want to call after each test-case execution. It works fine when I am not using above snippet(no multi threaded approach), but when i put above snippet to my settings file, the default sql_flush is called from django library. Below is the code snippet. Can you help me fixing this?

```
from django.core.servers.basehttp import WSGIServer
from django.test import testcases
from django.utils.six.moves import socketserver
testcases.WSGIServer = type(str('WSGIServer'), 
    (socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, WSGIServer), {})

from django.core.management import sql
sql.sql_flush = sql_flush_without_cms #this is custom flush function
```

This is the error I face :

> CommandError: Database test_db couldn't be flushed.   Possible
>   reasons:
>   * The database isn't running or isn't configured correctly.
>   * At least one of the expected database tables doesn't exist.
>   * The SQL was invalid.
>   Hint: Look at the output of 'django-admin.py sqlflush'. That's the SQL 
>   this command wasn't able to run.
>   The full error: cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key 
>   constraint
>       DETAIL:  Table "authtoken_token" references "users_userprofile".
>       HINT:  Truncate table "authtoken_token" at the same time, or use 
>       TRUNCATE ... CASCADE.

Comment: This is the ref link i used to create multithreaded live test server :  https://gist.github.com/kane-c/191cde363fe555cd4fb0

Comment: Hey techies, No solution ??